# Metaphorical use of 害虫

Tags: words

The title of the film *害虫* (2001) was literally translated into English as "Harmful Insect".

It is clear to me that the original title is a figure of speech. Is it a established metaphor (and how would you translate it?), or did the creators of the film just use that word creatively?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an established idiomatic expression. It does not have any surprising connotation unique to the Japanese language, such as [大根](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%A7%E6%A0%B9) ("radish" → unskilled actor / ham actor) and [鳥頭](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%B3%A5%E9%A0%AD) ("birdhead" → a person who forgets things soon).

It's not really a "creative" metaphor unique to this film, either. I believe harmful/useless people have been referred to as 害虫(のような人間) hundreds of times in works by various novelists and lyricists. For what it's worth, I checked the first 200 hits of 害虫 on [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/), and two of them were figurative. And here are [the results of 害虫 on Uta-Net](https://www.uta-net.com/user/index_search/search2.html?frm=ichiran&kw=%E5%AE%B3%E8%99%AB), a lyrics search engine.